# Placing camera with animation

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to know that how to place camera near and far (By increasing and decreasing value of eyeZ    `self.camera setEyeX:0 eyeY:0 eyeZ:1];`  `self.camera setEyeX:0 eyeY:0 eyeZ:180];`) including animation (for smoothness), as normally it provide jerky zooming.

Comment: I guess the following link will help you to solve the problem. [Basic Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html). Look at the **Explicit Animation** in that page.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is creating your own subclass of `CCActionInterval`, say `CCCameraZoomAnimation` and override its `update` method. The main advantage of having an action, aside from being able to control the camera movement finely, is also the possibility of using this action through `CCEaseOut`/`CCEaseIn` (etc.) to obtain nice graphical effects.

`CCCameraZoomAnimation` would have the node whose camera you want to modify as a target and another parameter to the constructor specifying the final Z value.

```
 @interface CCActionEase : CCActionInterval <NSCopying>
 {
       CCActionInterval * other;
 }
 /** creates the action */
 +(id) actionWithDuration:(ccTime)t finalZ:(float)finalZ;
 /** initializes the action */
 -(id) initWithDuration:(ccTime)t finalZ:(float)finalZ;
 @end
```

The `update` method is called with an argument `dt` which represents the elapsed time since the start of the action and would allow you to easily calculate the current Z position:

```
 -(void) update: (ccTime) t
 {
    // Get the camera's current values.
    float centerX, centerY, centerZ;
    float eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ;
    [_target.camera centerX:&centerX centerY:&centerY centerZ:&centerZ];
    [_target.camera eyeX:&eyeX eyeY:&eyeY eyeZ:&eyeZ];

    eyeZ = _intialZ + _delta * t  //-- just a try at modifying the camera

    // Set values.
    [_target.camera setCenterX:newX centerY:newY centerZ:0];
    [_target.camera setEyeX:newX eyeY:newY eyeZ:eyeZ];
 }
```

You would also need to implement `copyWithZone`:

```
 -(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone*) zone
 {
      CCAction *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone: zone] initWithDuration: [self duration] finalZ:_finalZ];
      return copy;
  }
```

and make use of `startWithTarget` to

```
  -(void) startWithTarget:(CCNode *)aTarget
  {
      [super startWithTarget:aTarget];
      _initialZ = _target.camera....;  //-- get the current value for eyeZ
      _delta = ccpSub( _finalZ, _initialZ );
  }
```

Nothing more, nothing less.

Sorry if copy/paste/modify produced some bugs, but I hope that the general idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

if you increase the 'z' by 180 from the off, you are bound to get a jerky animation, try running this in an animation context loop,increasing the value over a period of time will allow you to have a smooth 'zoom'.

Comment: You have mentioned 'y', do you really mean it? Coz I'm using Z to move camera near and far.

Comment: sorry, i did indeed mean 'Z' - i have changed answer accordingly.